avoid using the information in the "Extra" section of Zotero
I'm using biblatex and Zotero to manage reference on my paper. However, I keep adding the information stored in the "Extra" section of Zotero to the bibliogrphy, so the reference became like this:
van Bork, R., Rhemtulla, M., Waldorp, L. J., Kruis, J., Rezvanifar, S., & Borsboom, D. (2021).
Latent variable models and networks: Statistical equivalence and testability [Publisher:
CONFIRMATORY NETWORK FIT INDICES 43
Routledge _eprint: https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2019.1672515]. Multivariate
Behavioral Research, 56(2), 175–198
This part is unnecessary:
[Publisher:
CONFIRMATORY NETWORK FIT INDICES 43
Routledge _eprint: https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2019.1672515]
I noticed that in the .bib file this reference is written as follows and this extra information is written in note = {}:
@article{van_bork_latent_2021,
    title = {Latent Variable Models and Networks: Statistical Equivalence and Testability},
    volume = {56},
    issn = {0027-3171},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2019.1672515},
    doi = {10/ggf5h5},
    shorttitle = {Latent Variable Models and Networks},
    abstract = {Networks are gaining popularity as an alternative to latent variable models for representing psychological constructs. Whereas latent variable approaches introduce unobserved common causes to explain the relations among observed variables, network approaches posit direct causal relations between observed variables. While these approaches lead to radically different understandings of the psychological constructs of interest, recent articles have established mathematical equivalences that hold between network models and latent variable models. We argue that the fact that for any model from one class there is an equivalent model from the other class does not mean that both models are equally plausible accounts of the data-generating mechanism. In many cases the constraints that are meaningful in one framework translate to constraints in the equivalent model that lack a clear interpretation in the other framework. Finally, we discuss three diverging predictions for the relation between zero-order correlations and partial correlations implied by sparse network models and unidimensional factor models. We propose a test procedure that compares the likelihoods of these models in light of these diverging implications. We use an empirical example to illustrate our argument.},
    pages = {175--198},
    number = {2},
    journaltitle = {Multivariate Behavioral Research},
    author = {van Bork, Riet and Rhemtulla, Mijke and Waldorp, Lourens J. and Kruis, Joost and Rezvanifar, Shirin and Borsboom, Denny},
    urldate = {2021-09-19},
    date = {2021-03-04},
    keywords = {{LVNet}},
    note = {[Publisher:
CONFIRMATORY NETWORK FIT INDICES 43
Routledge _eprint: https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2019.1672515]} % here it is
}

As I have lots of papers in Zotero and it's almost impossible to go through all of the Extra section, I was wondering if there is a way to disable latex from using the information from note = {} in creating the bibliography?

I don't use Zotero, but I've only heard good things about the Better BibTeX extension (https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/) which lets you configure the exported .bib file. I expect there is a way to make it drop the unnecessary extra data.

solved by adding this to preamble to suppress the note section
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{note}%
}


The system automatically placed your answer in a review queue for potentially low quality posts (it got classified as OK, don't worry). You can reduce the risk of this happening again if you always include a small, but compilable example document in your answers (answer length is one factor for the classification).
